# Nuclear Fusion Rocket Problem

Tags: rocket-science

I bet on the problem of having the final speed of a spacecraft that has a fusion reactor that can move the star system with the bet of the friend. When the spacecraft's fusion efficiency is 0.01%, the spacecraft's fusion fuel is 1t, and the total mass of the spacecraft is 1.2t, the friend bet the final speed of the spacecraft is 80% of the speed of light. The state of the fuel at nuclear fusion is assumed to be D + T and 0.01% of the maximum energy of the fusion of the fuel, although the fusion method has not yet been firmly determined. I am curious about the answer of the final speed of this space ship.

Comment: Your fractions are wrong. Nuclear fission of U235 releases about 0.1% of rest-mass, and D-T fusion releases about 10 times more (1%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restating the numbers to make sure they're right:

- After burning the fuel, the remaining mass is 200kg
- Of the 1000kg of fuel burned, 0.1kg (0.01%) is turned into kinetic energy of the remaining mass.

If so, here's how you calculate the result:

$ \gamma = E/m = 200.1/200 = 1.0005$

From $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$, we get $v^2/c^2 = 1 - 1/\gamma^2$.

Plugging in the numbers:

$v = c \sqrt{1 - 1/1.0005^2} = 0.032 c$ or about 9,500 km/sec.

Fast, but not 0.8c. That would require $\gamma = 1.67$, which in turn requires a much higher efficiency and more fuel.

Comment: @Uus293 I did the arithmetic wrong 1st time, sorry. But you still win your bet.

Comment: Fractions are wrong. Nuclear fission of U235 releases about 0.1% of rest-mass, and D-T fusion releases about 10 times more (1%)